# nvd3 positive and negative value for same timestamp

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

Using [nvd3](https://github.com/novus/nvd3) library I am trying to display a positive and a negative "y" value for a same "x" value in a bar chart (like two inverted bars). The values are getting displayed but the negative value is also being plotted on the positive scale of the y-axis.

If I only display the negative values, it works correctly but in cases of both, it's not working as expected.

Below is what I have currently in my code:

```js
var chart;
nv.addGraph(function() {
  chart = nv.models.historicalBarChart();
  chart.useInteractiveGuideline(true);
  chart.xAxis.axisLabel("Time (s)");
  chart.yAxis.axisLabel('Voltage (v)');

  d3.select('#chart svg')
    .datum(sinAndCos())
    .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
  return chart;
});

function sinAndCos() {
  var sin = [], cos = [];
    
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    sin.push({
      x: i,
      y: i
    });

    cos.push({
      x: i,
      y: -(i)
    });
  }

  return [
  {
      values: sin,
      key: "Sine Wave",
      color: "#ff7f0e"
    },
    {
      values: cos,
      key: "Cosine Wave",
      color: "#2ca02c"
    }
  ];
}
```

```css
 text {
   font: 12px sans-serif;
 }

 svg {
   display: block;
 }

 html, body, #chart, svg {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.6/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.6/nv.d3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="chart">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```

Here is the link to JSFiddle which reproduces the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/prerak6962/a1zh9o4e/14/

Is there anything that I am missing or I need to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a different bar chart gives a better result

- `chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart();`
- `chart = nv.models.multiBarChart();`

```js
var chart;
nv.addGraph(function() {
  //chart = nv.models.historicalBarChart();
  chart = nv.models.multiBarChart();
  //chart.useInteractiveGuideline(true);
  chart.xAxis.axisLabel("Time (s)");
  chart.yAxis.axisLabel('Voltage (v)');

  d3.select('#chart svg')
    .datum(sinAndCos())
    .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
  return chart;
});

function sinAndCos() {
  var sin = [], cos = [];
    
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    sin.push({
      x: i,
      y: i
    });

    cos.push({
      x: i,
      y: -(i)
    });
  }

  return [
  {
      values: sin,
      key: "Sine Wave",
      color: "#ff7f0e"
    },
    {
      values: cos,
      key: "Cosine Wave",
      color: "#2ca02c"
    }
  ];
}
```

```css
 text {
   font: 12px sans-serif;
 }

 svg {
   display: block;
 }

 html, body, #chart, svg {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.6/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.6/nv.d3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="chart">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to use the same chart type, but nevertheless it can work for now.

Comment: @PrerakSola: find out what the difference is between these bar charts. the nvd3 docs are ...... (I can't find it on the main site)